# Time out by which search method returns otherwise it will throw time out message

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timeout

I want execute a search method by java main and want to implement the 
Time out by which search method returns otherwise it will throw a time out message. 
How can I achieve this time out functionality using thread or timer class?

Comment: This example may help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/Executesataskwithaspecifiedtimeout.htm. There are many other examples which can easily be found on Google.

Comment: You could always try [Object.wait(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

Comment: In the future please edit your post to show us a code sample and explain what you have tried and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to submit your search task to an executor, and [call `get(timeout);` on the returned future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) - in essence:

- create a Callable with your task
- run it with a timeout
- if it times out, cancel it - for the cancellation to work, your Callable needs to react to an interruption

```
Callable<SearchResult> task = ...;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<SearchResult> f = executor.submit(task);

SearchResult result = null;
try {
    result = f.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //2 seconds timeout
    return result;
} catch (TimeOutException e) {
    //handle the timeout, for example:
    System.out.println("The task took too long");
} finally {
    executor.shutdownNow(); //interrupts the task if it is still running
}
```